# Tengo un problema que al redirigir mi url se multiplica

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, href

Tengo un problema que al querer redirigir la URL crese, por ejemplo, al dar clic en una card me redirige a lo siguiente: `http://localhost/MiSitioWeb/Index/#/portfolio/portfolio-item-01.php?proyecto=1?proyecto=1`

Cuando la URL verdaderamente debería de ser: `http://localhost/MiSitioWeb/Index/#/portfolio/portfolio-item-01.php?proyecto=1`

Continuo el primer URL si me muestra el contenido, aunque aparezca dos veces en la URL, pero cuando regreso para salir del contenido y vuelvo a entrar la URL pasa a ser esta: `http://localhost/MiSitioWeb/Index/#/portfolio/portfolio-item-01.php?proyecto=1?proyecto=1`

Pasa a ser esta: `http://localhost/MiSitioWeb/Index/#/portfolio/portfolio-item-01.php?proyecto=1?proyecto=1?proyecto=1?proyecto=1`

Se multiplica y asi las veces que salga y entre de la card y me dice el siguiente ERROR: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?proyecto=1?proyecto=1?proyecto=1' at line 1`

Todo esto pasa usando esto como método para redirigir: `<a href="portfolio-item-01.php?proyecto=<?php echo $fila['id_portafolio'] ?>" class="ajax"></a>`

Ahora tengo otra en la cual si puedo entrar y salir las veces que yo quiera y me muestra el contenido correctamente solo que sigue el detalle de que la URL sigue incrementando cada vez que salgo y entro de la card el código es el siguiente: `<a href="portfolio-item-01.php?proyecto=<?php echo $fila['id_portafolio'] . '&amp;'; ?>" class="ajax"></a>`

**Archivo: portfolio.php**

```
<?php require_once "conexion.php";?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js classic-page-layout " data-audio-tick="audio/tick.mp3" data-click-ripple-animation="yes">


   

<body>
    <!-- PAGE -->
    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
        <!-- .site-main -->
        <main id="main" class="site-main cd-main">
            <!-- site-middle -->
            <div class="site-middle">
                <div class="layout-medium">
                    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                        <!-- site-content -->
                        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
                            <!-- .page-single -->
                            <div class="page-single page-layout">
                                <!-- .hentry -->
                                <article class="page hentry">
                                    <!-- .entry-header -->
                                    <header class="entry-header">
                                        <h1 class="entry-title">Portfolio</h1>
                                    </header>
                                    <!-- .entry-header -->
                                    <!-- .entry-content -->
                                    <div class="entry-content">
                                        <!--FILTERS-->
                                        <ul id="filters" class="filters">
                                            <li class="current">
                                                <a href="#" data-filter="*">Todo</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" data-filter=".media">Webs</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" data-filter=".illustration">Juegos</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <!--FILTERS-->
                                        <!-- PORTFOLIO -->
                                        <!--  <a href="portfolio-item-01.php?proyecto=<?php //echo $fila['id_portafolio'] . '&amp;';// ?>" class="ajax"></a> -->
                                        <div class="portfolio-items media-grid masonry" data-layout="masonry"
                                            data-item-width="360">
                                            <!-- portfolio-item -->
                                            <?php
                                                    $sentecia="SELECT * FROM portafolio";
                                                    $resultado= $conexion->query($sentecia) or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
                                                    while($fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                                            <div class="media-cell illustration hentry">
                                                <div class="media-box">
                                                    <img src="<?php echo $fila['imagen'];?>" alt="portfolio-post">
                                                    <div class="mask"></div>
                                                    <!--  <a href="portfolio-item-01.php?proyecto=<?php //echo $fila['id_portafolio'] . '&amp;?>" class="ajax"></a> -->
                                                    <a href="portfolio-item-01.php?proyecto=<?php echo $fila['id_portafolio']?>"
                                                        class="ajax"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="media-cell-desc">
                                                    <h3><?php echo $fila['nombre_proyecto'];?></h3>
                                                    <p class="category"><?php echo $fila['tipo'];?></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <!-- portfolio-item -->
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- PORTFOLIO -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- .entry-content -->
                                </article>
                                <!-- .hentry -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- .page-single -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- site-content -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- primary -->
                </div>
                <!-- layout -->
            </div>
            <!-- site-middle -->
        </main>
        <!-- .site-main -->
        <!-- ALERT : used for contact form mail delivery alert -->
        <div class="site-alert animated"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- PAGE -->

    <a href="#" id="back-to-top" class="show">↑ <span>Scroll to top</span></a>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
   
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Archivo main.js**

```
(function ($) {
  "use strict";

  /* global variables */
  var portfolioKeyword = "";
  var porftolioSingleActive = false;
  var porftolioSingleJustClosed = false;
  var soundEffects = false;
  var overlay_1, overlay_2, one_page_content, tick;
  var first_load = true;
  var userClickedAutoplayDialog = false;
  var homeLoaded = false;
  var autoplay = false;

  /* DOCUMENT LOAD */
  $(function () {

    
    // SET BG IMAGES for single page header bg image
    if ($(".header-wrap > img").length) {
      $(".header").css(
        "background-image",
        "url(" + $(".header-wrap > img").attr("src") + ")"
      );
    }

    // ------------------------------
    // ONE PAGE LAYOUT FUNCTIONS
    if ($("html").hasClass("one-page-layout")) {

      autoplay = $('#play-music').hasClass('autoplay') ? true : false;

      // add hash to links
      $(".home-menu a").each(function (index, element) {
        var menu_link = $(this);
        var file_url = menu_link.attr("href");
        var slug = menu_link.data("slug");

        menu_link.attr("href", "#/" + slug);
        menu_link.data("file-url", file_url);
      });

      $(".close-page").on("click", function (event) {
        // event.preventDefault();
        $.address.path("");
        history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);

        // Play Sound Effect
        if (soundEffects) {
          tick.play();
        }

        return false;
      });

      // PORTFOLIO DETAILS
      // if url contains a portfolio detail url
      portfolioKeyword = $("#portfolio-link").data("slug");

      // FULL BROWSER BACK BUTTON SUPPORT
      $.address.change(function () {
        //console.log('addres changed');

        var path = $.address.path();
        path = path.slice(1, path.length);

        // bug-fix : don't run if hash doesn't exist on first load
        if (path === "" && first_load) {
          first_load = false;
          return;
        }
        first_load = false;
        setActivePage();

        var detailUrl = giveDetailUrl();
        if (detailUrl !== -1) {
          showProjectDetails(detailUrl);
        } else {
          // if url contains portfolio keyword
          if ($.address.path().indexOf("/" + portfolioKeyword) !== -1) {
            if (porftolioSingleActive) {
              hideProjectDetails(true, false);
              porftolioSingleJustClosed = false;

              // when loaded url with portfolio single url, after closing portfolio single box; open portfolio page if it is not already opened...
              if ($(".one-page-content .content-wrap").is(":empty")) {
                setActivePage();
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }); // end address change event


    }
    // ------------------------------
    // MOUSE CLCIK RIPPLE EFFECT
    if ($('html').data("click-ripple-animation") === "yes") {
      $("html").append('<i class="ripple"></i>');
      $("html").on("mousedown", function (e) {
        $("i.ripple").addClass("active").css("left", e.pageX).css("top", e.pageY);
      });

      $("i.ripple").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () {
        return $("i.ripple").removeClass("active");
      });
    }
    // ------------------------------




    // ------------------------------
    // STICKY SIDEBAR
    sticky_sidebar();
    // ------------------------------

    fixMarquee();

    $(window).resize(function () {
      fixMarquee();
      sticky_sidebar_update(); // fix for : sticky sidebar overlap when resized to mobile view
    });

    // make portfolio grid titles clickable too ;)
    $('body').on("click", ".portfolio-items .media-cell-desc h3", function () {
      $(this).parent().siblings('.media-box').find('a').eq(0).trigger('click');
    });


    // ------------------------------
    // detect ios 12 to add css fixes   
    function iOSversion() {
      if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) {
        // supports iOS 2.0 and later: <https://bit.ly/TJjs1V>
        var v = (navigator.appVersion).match(/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/);
        return [parseInt(v[1], 10), parseInt(v[2], 10), parseInt(v[3] || 0, 10)];
      }
    }

    var ver = iOSversion();
    if (ver !== undefined) {
      if (ver[0] >= 12) {
        $('html').addClass('ios12');
      } else {
        $('html').addClass('not-ios12');
      }
    }
    // ------------------------------



    // ------------------------------
    // SETUP
    setup();
    // ----------------------------

  });
  // DOCUMENT READY

  // ------------------------------
  // ------------------------------
  // FUNCTIONS
  // ------------------------------
  // SETUP : plugins
  function setup() {

    // COOL LINKS
    coolLinks();

    // MASONRY
    setupMasonry();

    // LIGHTBOX
    setupLightbox();

    // FILL SKILL BARS
    fillBars();

    // PORTFOLIO SINGLE AJAX
    setupAjax();

    // FORMS
    setupForms();

    // CONTACT FORM
    setupContactForm();

    // TABS
    tabs();

    // TOGGLES
    toggles();

    // FLUID MEDIA
    fluidMedia();

  }
  // -----------------------------

  // ------------------------------
  // PORTFOLIO SINGLE AJAX
  function setupAjax() {
    // PORTFOLIO DETAILS
    // Show details
    $(
      ".one-page-layout .media-box .ajax, .one-page-layout .portfolio-nav .ajax a"
    ).on("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var url = $(this).attr("href");
      var baseUrl = $.address.baseURL();
      var detailUrl = giveDetailUrl();

      if (url.indexOf(baseUrl) !== -1) {
        // full url
        var total = url.length;
        detailUrl = url.slice(baseUrl.length + 1, total);
        $.address.path("/" + detailUrl);
      } else {
        // relative url
        detailUrl = url;
        $.address.path("/" + portfolioKeyword + "/" + detailUrl);

      }
    });
  }
  // ------------------------------

  // ------------------------------
  // MASONRY - ISOTOPE
  function setupMasonry() {
    var masonry = $(".masonry, .gallery, .wp-block-gallery:not(.is-cropped)");
    if (masonry.length) {
      masonry.each(function (index, el) {
        // call isotope
        refreshMasonry();
        $(el).imagesLoaded(function () {
          $(el).isotope({
            layoutMode: $(el).data("layout") ? $(el).data("layout") : "masonry"
          });
          // set columns
          refreshMasonry();
        });

        // filters
        if (!$(el).data("isotope")) {
          var filters = $(el).siblings(".filters");
          if (filters.length) {
            filters.find("a").on("click", function () {
              var selector = $(this).attr("data-filter");
              $(el).isotope({ filter: selector });
              $(this)
                .parent()
                .addClass("current")
                .siblings()
                .removeClass("current");
              return false;
            });
          }
        }
      }); //each
      $(window).on("resize debouncedresize", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
          refreshMasonry();
        }, 100);
      });
    }
  }
  // ------------------------------

  // ------------------------------
  // REFRSH MASONRY - ISOTOPE
  function refreshMasonry() {
    var masonry = $(".masonry");
    if (masonry.length) {
      masonry.each(function (index, el) {
        // check if isotope initialized
        if ($(el).data("isotope")) {
          var itemW = $(el).data("item-width");
          var containerW = $(el).width();
          var items = $(el).children(".hentry");
          var columns = Math.round(containerW / itemW);
          columns = $(window).width() <= 700 ? 2 : columns;

          // set the widths (%) for each of item
          items.each(function (index, element) {
            var multiplier = $(this).hasClass("x2") && columns > 1 ? 2 : 1;
            var itemRealWidth =
              ((Math.floor(containerW / columns) * 100) / containerW) *
              multiplier;
            $(this).css("width", itemRealWidth + "%");
          });

          var columnWidth = Math.floor(containerW / columns);

          $(el).isotope("option", { masonry: { columnWidth: columnWidth } });
          $(el).isotope("layout");
        }
      }); //each
    }
  }
  // ------------------------------

  // ------------------------------
  // LIGHTBOX - applied to porfolio and gallery post format
  function setupLightbox() {
    if ($(".lightbox, .gallery, .wp-block-gallery").length) {
      $(".media-box, .gallery, .wp-block-gallery").each(function (index, element) {
        var $media_box = $(this);
        $media_box.magnificPopup({
          delegate:
            '.lightbox, figure a[href$=".jpg"], figure a[href$=".jpeg"], figure a[href$=".png"], figure a[href$=".gif"], .gallery-item a[href$=".jpg"], .gallery-item a[href$=".jpeg"], .gallery-item a[href$=".png"], .gallery-item a[href$=".gif"]',
          type: "image",
          image: {
            markup:
              '<div class="mfp-figure">' +
              '<div class="mfp-close"></div>' +
              '<div class="mfp-img"></div>' +
              "</div>" +
              '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">' +
              '<div class="mfp-title"></div>' +
              '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>' +
              "</div>", // Popup HTML markup. `.mfp-img` div will be replaced with img tag, `.mfp-close` by close button

            cursor: "mfp-zoom-out-cur", // Class that adds zoom cursor, will be added to body. Set to null to disable zoom out cursor.
            verticalFit: true, // Fits image in area vertically
            tError: '<a href="%url%">The image</a> could not be loaded.' // Error message
          },
          gallery: {
            enabled: true,
            tCounter: '<span class="mfp-counter">%curr% / %total%</span>' // markup of counter
          },
          iframe: {
            markup:
              '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">' +
              '<div class="mfp-close"></div>' +
              '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' +
              '<div class="mfp-title">Some caption</div>' +
              "</div>"
          },
          mainClass: "mfp-zoom-in",
          tLoading: "",
          removalDelay: 300, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
          callbacks: {
            markupParse: function (template, values, item) {
              var title = "";
              if (item.el.parents(".gallery-item").length) { // classic editor gallery
                title = item.el
                  .parents(".gallery-item")
                  .find(".gallery-caption")
                  .text();
              } else if (item.el.parents(".blocks-gallery-item").length) { // Gutenberg gallery
                title = item.el
                  .parents(".blocks-gallery-item")
                  .find("figcaption")
                  .text();
              }
              else {
                title =
                  item.el.data("title") == undefined
                    ? ""
                    : item.el.data("title");
              }
              //return title;
              values.title = title;
            },
            imageLoadComplete: function () {
              var self = this;
              setTimeout(function () {
                self.wrap.addClass("mfp-image-loaded");
              }, 16);
            },
            beforeClose: function () {
              // play bg audio when closing audio/video in a lightbox
              if (this.content.find('iframe[src*="soundcloud.com"]').length || this.content.find('iframe[src*="vimeo.com"]').length || this.content.find('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]').length) {
                if (!isUserTurnedOffMusic) {
                  if (music) {
                    music.play();
                    isLigtboxTurnedOffMusic = false;
                  }

                }
              }
            },
            close: function () {
              this.wrap.removeClass("mfp-image-loaded");

            },
            beforeAppend: function () {
              var self = this;

              // pause bg audio when opening audio/video in a lightbox
              if (this.content.find('iframe[src*="soundcloud.com"]').length || this.content.find('iframe[src*="vimeo.com"]').length || this.content.find('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]').length) {
                self.wrap.addClass("is-soundcloud");
                if (music) {
                  isLigtboxTurnedOffMusic = true;
                  music.pause();
                }
              }

              // square aspect ratio for soundcloud embeds
              if (this.content.find('iframe[src*="soundcloud.com"]').length) {
                self.wrap.addClass("is-soundcloud");
              } else {
                self.wrap.removeClass("is-soundcloud");
              }

              this.content.find("iframe").on("load", function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                  self.wrap.addClass("mfp-image-loaded");
                }, 16);
              });
            }
          },
          closeBtnInside: false,
          closeOnContentClick: true,
          midClick: true
        });
      });
    }
  }
  // ------------------------------

 
  // ------------------------------
  // AJAX PORTFOLIO DETAILS
  var pActive;

  function showProjectDetails(url) {
    porftolioSingleJustClosed = true;
    porftolioSingleActive = true;

    showLoader();

    var p = $(".p-overlay:not(.active)").first();
    pActive = $(".p-overlay.active");

    // ajax : fill data
    p.empty().load(url + " .portfolio-single", function () {
      NProgress.set(0.5);

      p.prepend(p.find('.portfolio-nav').clone());

      // wait for images to be loaded
      p.imagesLoaded(function () {
        hideLoader();

        if (pActive.length) {
          hideProjectDetails();
        }

        $("html").addClass("p-overlay-on");

        // setup plugins
        setup();

        $("html").addClass("p-animating");

        // Play Sound Effect
        if (soundEffects) {
          tick.play();
        }

        p.removeClass("animate-in animate-out")
          .addClass("animate-in")
          .show()
          .scrollTop(0);
        p.addClass("active");

        p.one(
          "webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend",
          function (e) {
            $("html").removeClass("p-animating");
          }
        );
      });
    });
  }

  function hideProjectDetails(forever, safeClose) {
    porftolioSingleJustClosed = true;

    // Play Sound Effect
    if (soundEffects) {
      tick.play();
    }

    $("html").addClass("p-animating");

    // close completely by back link.
    if (forever) {
      pActive = $(".p-overlay.active");

      $("html").removeClass("p-overlay-on");

      if (!safeClose) {
        // remove detail url
        $.address.path(portfolioKeyword);
      }
    }

    pActive
      .removeClass("active animate-in animate-out")
      .addClass("animate-out")
      .show();

    pActive.one(
      "webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend",
      function (e) {
        $("html").removeClass("p-animating");
        pActive
          .hide()
          .removeClass("animate-out")
          .empty();
      }
    );

    setTimeout(function () {
      pActive
        .hide()
        .removeClass("animate-out")
        .empty();
    }, 550);
  }
  
  function giveDetailUrl() {
    var address = $.address.value();
    var detailUrl;

    if (
      address.indexOf("/" + portfolioKeyword + "/") != -1 &&
      address.length > portfolioKeyword.length + 2
    ) {
      var total = address.length;
      detailUrl = address.slice(portfolioKeyword.length + 2, total);
    } else {
      detailUrl = -1;
    }
    return detailUrl;
  }

  
  // ------------------------------

  // ------------------------------
  // AJAX LOADER
  function showLoader() {
    NProgress.start();
  }
  function hideLoader() {
    NProgress.done();
  }
  // ------------------------------

  // ------------------------------
  // SET ACTIVE PAGE
  function setActivePage() {
    var path = $.address.path();
    path = path.slice(1, path.length);

    // if hash tag doesnt exists - close page
    if (path === "") {
      closePage();
    } else {
      // show page change animation
      // change page only if url doesn't target portfolio single page
      //console.log(porftolioSingleJustClosed);

      if (porftolioSingleJustClosed) {
        porftolioSingleJustClosed = false;
      } else {
        if (giveDetailUrl() === -1) {
          //porftolioSingleJustClosed = false;
          var new_url = $("a[data-slug=" + path + "]").data("file-url");
          showPage(new_url);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // ------------------------------

  // ------------------------------
  // SHOW PAGE
  function showPage(url) {
    // start layers animation
    overlay_1.css("transition-delay", ".0s").css("transform", "translateY(0%)");
    overlay_2.css("transition-delay", ".2s").css("transform", "translateY(0%)");

    var transitionEnded = false;
    overlay_2.one(
      "webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
      function () {
        transitionEnded = true;
      });

    // Play Sound Effect
    if (soundEffects) {
      tick.play();
    }

    $("html").addClass("is-ajax-page-active");

    // only jquery get() returns remote page's <head> content
    jQuery.get(url, function (data) {

      // clear container content
      one_page_content.children(".content-wrap").empty();

      // elementor styles fix
      one_page_content
        .children(".content-wrap")
        .append($(data).filter("#elementor-frontend-inline-css")) // elementor inline styles
        .append($(data).filter("link[id^='elementor-post-']")) // elementor external styles
        .append($(data).filter("link[id='elementor-frontend-css']")); // elemementor common styles

      // place page content
      one_page_content
        .children(".content-wrap")
        .append($(data).find(".page-single > .hentry"));

      // wait for images to be loaded
      one_page_content.imagesLoaded(function () {

        $("html").addClass("is-ajax-page-loaded");

        if (transitionEnded) {
          showLoadedPage();
        } else {

          // wait for layers animation end if it is not ended yet
          overlay_2.one(
            "webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
            function () {
              showLoadedPage();
            }
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }

  function showLoadedPage() {

    console.log('overlay_2.one transitionend');
    one_page_content.addClass("is-visible");
    overlay_2
      .css("transition-delay", ".0s")
      .css("transform", "translateY(100%)");
    overlay_1
      .css("transition-delay", ".2s")
      .css("transform", "translateY(100%)");
    var t = setTimeout(function () {
      $("html").addClass("is-ajax-page-visible");
      clearTimeout(t);
    }, 100);

    setup();
  }


})(jQuery);
```

este es el código y todo lo que está relacionado con la redirección

Comment: Tu código está incompleto, no incluyes cosas como la función `giveDetailUrl()` o la inicialización de la variable `portfolioKeyword`, por mencionar solo 2 problemas. Te recomiendo preparar un [mcve] y editar tu pregunta. Mi percepción actual es que el código php no es relevante, pero si creo que hace falta algo de HTML.

Comment: lo acabo de modificar subí ambos archivos completos quite algunas cosas que no tienen nada que ver por ejemplo el head,etc. te agradecería un motón si lo puedes revisar de nuevo <3

Comment: Hola Abraham, cuando respondas algún comentario, coloca **@nombreDelUsuario** para que este sea notificado de tu respuesta, en este caso sería: @jachguate, (ahora el sabe que respondiste).

Comment: Hay demasiado código y siguen habiendo cosas en PHP que no creo que estén relacionadas. Una parte del [mcve] es que sea **mínimo**, es decir, que tenga solo lo esencial para poder reproducir el comportamiento. Eso lo tiene que hacer alguien y es poco probable que quien sepa encontrar el problema y se tome el tiempo de responder, además tenga el tiempo de hacerlo, así que es mejor que lo hagas tu, @Abraham. Yo, por ejemplo, he pasado el código  para intentar reproducir tu problema, pero hay tanto de más que, por segunda vez, desisto de intentarlo.

Comment: Mínimo sería, creo que 4 o 5 líneas en HTML y el código esencial de javascript. Actualmente estás publicando más de 100 líenas de html, con php incluido, lo que implica que no puede ejecutarse directamente, y 602 líneas de javascript!!.